# How to hide/show a div using Javascript for input validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

As you can see the above warning will be only shown when there is an error while inserting the data into the login form.
Now I have tried to achieve it by:

1. Hiding the div say "warning".
2. Use a javascript while submitting the form to check for input
   validation.
3. If found any error, the hidden div "warning" will show above the
   form as shown as in the image.

does it has something to do with

```
visibility: hidden;
```

I have tried it in http://jsfiddle.net/w2udrm3q/

Ples help

Comment: You're using jQuery, and jQuery doesn't count elements with `visibility: hidden` as hidden as they still take up space, so yes, it has something to do with that.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use jQuery in your posted JS Fiddle link, but haven't included it in the demo.

Comment: Ohh sorry about the jQuery. But can it be done without jQuery? I will be happy to use javascript, but any solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#id{display:none;}
```

**JS**

```
if (!(x==="test")) {document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'block';}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `display:none` CSS property to hide Warning division.